# Ant junitlauncher task causes "Failed to launch in-vm tests" error

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit5

I'm trying to run my unit tests using an Ant build script version 1.10.12 with the junitlauncher task. I have verified absolutely everything three to four times over at this point and even reviewed the source code for this task on github [https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitlauncher.html][1].

The error is

> Failed to launch in-vm tests

and the stack trace is

> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junitlauncher.confined.JUnitLauncherTask.launchViaReflection(JUnitLauncherTask.java:223)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junitlauncher.confined.JUnitLauncherTask.execute(JUnitLauncherTask.java:105)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:190)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:274)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:31) Caused
> by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junitlauncher.confined.JUnitLauncherTask.launchViaReflection(JUnitLauncherTask.java:221)

Reviewing the method in the source code where the error happens is not helpful and the error message is meaning less and entirely undocumented according to the research I've done.

The target in my script

```
 <target name="unittest" description="Run units tests">
      <junitlauncher haltOnFailure="false" printSummary="true">
          <classpath refid="junit.class.path"/>
          <classpath refid="mcwr.runtime.module.classpath"/>
          <testclasses outputdir="testreports">
              <fileset dir="${mcwr.testoutput.dir}">
              </fileset>
              <listener type="legacy-brief" sendSysOut="true"/>
              <listener type="legacy-xml" sendSysErr="true" sendSysOut="true"/>
          </testclasses>
      </junitlauncher>
  </target>
```

At this point I'm entirely stuck. What does this error mean and how do I go about resolving it?

Here is the source code (the method is "launchViaReflection" https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/master/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junitlauncher/confined/JUnitLauncherTask.java

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this problem and finally got by it.  You may be getting an error about the XML listeners further down in your stacktrace?  The directory defined by

```
<testclasses outputdir="DIRECTORY">
```

has to exist ahead of time.  You can add something like

```
<mkdir dir="DIRECTORY"/>
```

to the top of your "unittest" target.

The other thing is the "DIRECTORY" value seems to require an absolute path for testclasses, so while

```
<mkdir dir="testreports"/>
```

may create your directory at the basedir just fine,

```
<testclasses outputDir="testreports">
```

will cause an error.

You can create a property with "location" rather than "value"

```
<property name="testreports" location="testreports" />
<testclasses outputDir="${testreports}">
```

or use the basedir property to give an absolute path

```
<testclasses outputDir="${basedir}/testreports">
```